Is it possible to anonymously access SMB, or login multiple times concurrently?
I have an Asustor NAS (FS6706T) that is primarily a local media-sharing device.
I have multiple machines that should access the shared folders.
Currently, I must login "Enter Network Credentials" (on Windows) on each machine where I want to access the files.
And if I am already logged in on another machine, access is denied:

All I want is that every computer on the local LAN can access the files in a Shared Folder.

is this possible?
or can I somehow login multiple times concurrently to resolve this?


All I want is that every computer on the local LAN can access the files in a Shared Folder. You aren't doing that. There is already a connection from the host you are on to the share. You need to identify the source of that connection.

Can you verify with Wireshark what kind of error you're really getting from the server? This smells like a deliberate NAS-side restriction.

Guest logons from a Windows client have been disabled by default since Windows 10, almost 10 years.
There is documentation on how to circumvent that security practice here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/enable-insecure-guest-logons-smb2-and-smb3
Note that both SMB signing and SMB encryption policies be disabled to use guest logons. All around a lose-lose.
Other alternatives include:

Connect to the target server using the IP address

Create a different name (CNAME) for the server/IP address and connect to that name.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/cannot-connect-to-network-share
